# Reading unstructured data using PHP into MySQL Database Problem

Tags: php, mysql, database, json, phpmyadmin

I have the following PHP code that reads in data from a formatted text file, with data separated by commas.

```
    // Create database gameDB
    if (mysql_query('create database gameDB', $connection)) {
        echo "Database gameDB created successfully.\n";
    } else {
        echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n:";
    }

    // select which database to use
    mysql_select_db('gameDB', $connection);

    // create table xyzcoord if it doesn't already exist
    mysql_query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xyzcoord (
        Frame varchar(100),
        X varchar(100),
        Y varchar(100),
        Z varchar(100))', $connection);

    $wx = array_map('trim',file("20-frames-xyz-coordinates.txt"));
    $newwx = array();
    foreach($wx as $i => $line)
    {
            if ($i > 1)
            {
                    $tmp = array_filter(explode(' ',$line));
                    $q = "insert into xyzcoord (Frame, X, Y, Z) values ('" . implode("','",$tmp) . "')";
                    $rw = mysql_query($q) or die("Problem with the query: $q<br>" . mysql_error());
            }
    }
?>
```

My problem is I have a different text file I need to read in where the data is unstructured in the format below, for 60 frames.

```
(new line) Frame_0100
(new line) X_coordinates
(new line) 23.90,23.90,23.94,23.98,24.02,24.02,24.06
(new line) Y_coordinates
(new line) 5.55,6.15,5.55,5.55,5.51,5.55,5.51
(new line) Z_coordinates
(new line) 0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
(new line)
(new line) Frame_0101
(new line) X_coordinates
(new line) 23.90,23.90,23.94,23.98,24.02,24.02,24.06
(new line) Y_coordinates
(new line) 5.55,6.15,5.55,5.55,5.51,5.55,5.51
(new line) Z_coordinates
(new line) 0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
(new line)
(new line) Frame_0102
(new line) X_coordinates
(new line) 23.90,23.90,23.94,23.98,24.02,24.02,24.06
...etc
```

I am hoping to read in this data that is not already formatted, and store it in MySQL DB into tables. Im not sure how I can read the data in the format its in using PHP. I have considered using JSON. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so you have many x,y,z coord for each frame?

Comment: Yes and I need to read it in MySQL as Frame1(row) - X(column) Y(column) Z(column). Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the first two lines are blank and then the data starts uninterrupted on line 3 (index = 2); the numbers at the top will have to be changed if that is mistaken. Otherwise, replace your foreach loop with this and it should work:

```
foreach($wx as $i => $line)
{
        if ($i > 1 and ($i-2)%4 == 0)
        {
                $q = "insert into xyzcoord (Frame, X, Y, Z) values ('" . $line . str_replace('X_coordinates ','',$wx[$i+1]) . str_replace('Y_coordinates ','',$wx[$i+2]) . str_replace('Z_coordinates ','',$wx[$i+3]) . "')";
                $rw = mysql_query($q) or die("Problem with the query: $q<br>" . mysql_error());
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong. The data starts on the third line, I made an edit for this. I can change your method above to suit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To be honest I cant figure your if statement. Im new to PHP so I hope you can forgive my naivety/idiocy. I know its just changing the index to 3 but the way you have coded it I cant figure how to do that. If you could explain that would be great.